# Javascript & https - XMLHttpRequest object to GET relative path - is protocol/port 'inherited'?

Tags: javascript, https, xmlhttprequest

If I use relative paths in Javascript to GET a page from a server (to display output inside a div), does Javascript use the same protocol/port as the page in which it was loaded?

For example:

parent page is requested https://www.foo.com/bar.php

JS code on bar.php:

```
var turl = "/new_dir/index.php?r="+r;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){  
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",turl,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Since the parent page was requested and served using https on port 443 does this mean that JS will send the GET request to the new page using the same protocol and port? Or will it send the request via http on port 80 since I did not specify a connection protocol in the 'turl' variable?

Comment: It will inherit, try it out, you can sue fiddler to see where request are being sent or you can just use firefox with firebug and look in the nettab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will use the same port and protocol, since you haven't specified anything else. Your URL is a *relative reference* in RFC-speak, details in [Section 4.2 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2). (I only happen to know the RFC section reference because I just recently found out about [this nifty trick](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html) for http/https stuff.)

So your request for

```
/new_dir/index.php?r=blah
```

relative to the document

```
http://www.foo.com/bar.php
```

resolves to

```
http://www.foo.com/new_dir/index.php?r=blah
```

Comment: just put a copy of my website underneath a different apache and php version. And suddenly the xmlHttp.open URL's cannot be resolved anymore. (this website has been running for over 5 years). I'm guessing that the config or version of the webserver plays a role in it as well.

Comment: @bvdb: No, it doesn't. This is governed by specification and by the time the browser makes the request, the request will be site-relative anyway.

Comment: turned out, to be something else . *oopz*